Sending Document Identifier from Office Add-in to Backend Service
I am integrating our backend service (built with Java Spring Boot) with a Microsoft Word add-in (built with Angular).
Current Setup:

Our backend service creates a DriveItem for a Word document
programmatically using the Microsoft Graph SDK for Java and uploads it to the user's OneDrive.

The user is then redirected to a URL (webUrl) that opens the Word
document in a new tab.


Requirement:
When a button is clicked in our Office add-in for Microsoft Word, it needs to transmit the document's information or ID to our backend service. This will allow the backend to identify or reconstruct the related DriveItem.
Thoughts and Attempts:
1. Query Parameter Approach:

The backend service adds a query parameter like DocumentId to the
webUrl.

The add-in in Microsoft Word reads that query parameter and sends it
back to the backend.

Issue: Office.context.document.url doesn't return the query string associated with the URL.


2. Custom Properties Approach:

The backend service adds the DocumentId to additional data
(FieldsValueSet) of the ListItem.

The add-in reads the DocumentId from the document properties.

Concern: I'm not sure if these custom properties can be read via
Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAysnc().


3. GraphServiceClient shares() Method Approach:

To use the shares() method of Graph-SDK on the server side, we need to pass the encoded URL (webUrl) of the document.

Concern: Can shares() Method resolve the related DriveItem with the URL returned by the Office JavaScript API Office.context.document.url


Question:
Am I missing another useful approach? How can I achieve this? Are there any other methods or best practices to send information from the Office add-in to the backend service for identifying the associated DriveItem?

Meanwhile I solved the problem with the shares() method of GraphServiceClient. This method can resolve document url to an DriveItem instance.
